# Approximate $f(x)$ using $\frac{d}{dx} [f(x)]$ and $f(x - 1)$

Tags: functions, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I want to calculate $f(x)$, knowing the values of $\frac{d}{dx} [f(x)]$ and $f(x - 1)$.

For sample:
$f(x) = x^3$
I want to calculate $f(3)$, and I know that $f(x) = x^3$, $f(2) = 8$ and $\frac{d}{dx} [f(x)] = 3x^2$.

I tried $f(x - 1) + \frac{d}{dx} [f(x)]$, but it didn't work.

> It seems that what you're trying to do is to use "Taylor's Theorem" to get a linear approximation of the function.

How to do it (I already know the Taylor series)? Will I use $\frac{d}{dx} [f(x)]$ or $\frac{d}{dx} [f(x - 1)]$?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By Taylor's Theorem the approximation of $f(x)$ centered in $c$ is:
$P_n(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n} \frac{f^{(i)}(c)}{i!} (x - c)^i$
Where $n$ is the precision of the approximation, if $n$ be equal to the "*depth*" of the function $P_n(x) = f(x)$.

The "*depth*" of the function $f(x) = x^3$ is $3$ (the "*depth*" of a linear function is $1$, of a quadratic is $2$, of a cubic is $3$, ...).

We already know the value of $f(x - 1)$ then the "*approximmation*" will be centered in $x$ (we're going to calculate $f(x + 1)$):
$f(x + 1) = \sum_{i = 0}^{3} \frac{f(x)}{i!} (x + 1 - x)^i$

$f(x + 1) = \frac{f(x)}{0!} + \frac{f'(x)}{1!} + \frac{f''(x)}{2!} + \frac{f'''(x)}{3!} = f(x) + f'(x) + \frac{f''(x)}{2} + \frac{f'''(x)}{6}$

Now we calculate $\frac{d}{dx} (x^3) = 3x^2$, $\frac{d}{dx} (3x^2) = 6x$ and $\frac{d}{dx} (6x) = 6$, plugging these values:
$f(x + 1) = x^3 + 3x^2 + \frac{6x}{2} + \frac{6}{6}$

Therefore $f(x + 1) = x^3 + 3x^2 + 3x + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you're trying to do is to use "Taylor's Theorem" to get a linear approximation of the function. Basically, you can obtain a result that should agree with the actual value, provided you are not too far from the point at which you know the function. Since $x^3$ grows pretty quickly, the approximation also gets worse quickly.

Comment: Is what I want! How to use the Taylor series for this? Will I use $\frac{d}{dx} [f(x)]$?